# invoke-webrequest powershell no results

Tags: powershell

just got a simple code from my friend.

He wants to fill a form on a website and save the results.
The code fills the fields correctly, but thats it, nothing more.

I'm new to coding so andybod can help me / has a hint?

```
$R = Invoke-WebRequest -URI https://kfz2.virtuelles-rathaus.de/igv/servlet/Internetgeschaeftsvorfaelle?MANDANT=08215000"&"AUFRUF=WKZ -SessionVariable fb
$Form = $R.Forms[0]
$Form.fields

$Form.Fields["INPUT-TXT_KENNZEICHENSUCHE_ERKENNUNGSZEICHEN"]="MK"
$Form.Fields["INPUT-TXT_KENNZEICHENSUCHE_ZIFFERN"]="??"

$Uri = "https://kfz2.virtuelles-rathaus.de/igv/servlet/Internetgeschaeftsvorfaelle?MANDANT=08215000&AUFRUF=WKZ" + $Form.Action


$R = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -WebSession $FB -Method POST -Body $Form.Fields
```

Comment: What else do you want to happen?

Comment: I want to save the results (if existing)

Comment: You don't know whether there is a return? If the call is working and `$R` is empty, then maybe there is no return.

Comment: Tried with other inputs. Didn't work either. Filling the forms works, but submitting and returning the results not.